# Renaming files in a folder using powershell excluding certain extension

Tags: powershell, rename

I use the following Powershell script to rename files in folders (removing a part from the file name). But I want to do this for all files except .dxl files.

```
Get-ChildItem <location> -Recurse |
    Where-Object { $_.Extension -ne 'dxl' } |
    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName { (($_.BaseName -replace '(.*)-.*?$','$1') + $_.Extension) }
```

Comment: Replace `$.` with `$_.`

Comment: You mean `Get-ChildItem <location> -recurse -exclude *.dxl`?

Comment: @marsze it's that easy indeed. However, face another issue: file already exist

Comment: That's *your* problem. :P You cannot have two files with the same name of course. Then you should change your requirements and do a different replace.

Comment: The code you posted cannot possibly work since you're feeding pipeline input into `Rename-Item` while at the same time passing `$_.FullName` (which is not populated at that point) to the parameter `-Path`.